# Exchange with Powershell - Weird Error

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I input my code and it is throwing an error. The code ran fine and I was able to get it to run through before I tried adding in the dropbox feature. I cant seem to figure out what is wrong with this...

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly] does not contain a method named 'op_A
At C:\scripts\tmail1.ps1:127 char:1
+ $return2 = ($return[0] + " " + $return[1])
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly] does not contain a method named 'op_A
At C:\scripts\tmail1.ps1:128 char:1
+ $return3 = ($return[0] + "." + $return[1])
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Method invocation failed because [System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly] does not contain a method named 'op_A
At C:\scripts\tmail1.ps1:129 char:1
+ $return4 = $return[0] + "." + $return[1] + $return[2]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Alias'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is
empty, and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Mailbox], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,New-Mailbox
    + PSComputerName        : pqhiexch01.xxxxxxx.com

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-User], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Set-User
```

My Code is as followed:

```
function button ($title,$mailbx, $WF, $TF) {

###################Load Assembly for creating form & button######

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)

#####Define the form size & placement

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 750;
$form.Height = 500;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;

##############Define text label1
$textLabel1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel1.Left = 25;
$textLabel1.Top = 15;

$textLabel1.Text = $mailbx;

##############Define text label2

$textLabel2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel2.Left = 25;
$textLabel2.Top = 50;

$textLabel2.Text = $WF;

##############Define text label3

########################

# Edit This item to change the DropDown Values

[array]$DropDownArray = "@yahoo.com", "@gmail.com", "@msn.com"

$textLabel3 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel3.Left = 25;
$textLabel3.Top = 85;

$textLabel3.Text = $TF;

############Define text box1 for input
$textBox1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox1.Left = 150;
$textBox1.Top = 10;
$textBox1.width = 200;

############Define text box2 for input

$textBox2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox2.Left = 150;
$textBox2.Top = 50;
$textBox2.width = 200;

############Define text box3 for input

# This Function Returns the Selected Value and Closes the Form

function Return-DropDown {

 $Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
 }

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")




$DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,90)
$DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(200,30)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
 $DropDown.Items.Add($Item)
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,90) 
$DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20) 
$DropDownLabel.Text = "Items"
#############Define default values for the input boxes
$defaultValue = “”
$textBox1.Text = $defaultValue;
$textBox2.Text = $defaultValue;


#############define OK button
$button = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$button.Left = 360;
$button.Top = 85;
$button.Width = 100;
$button.Text = “Ok”;

############# This is when you have to close the form after getting values
$eventHandler = [System.EventHandler]{
$textBox1.Text;
$textBox2.Text;
$dropdown.Items;
$form.Close();};

$button.Add_Click($eventHandler) ;

#############Add controls to all the above objects defined
$form.Controls.Add($button);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel1);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel2);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel3);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox2);
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)
$Button.Add_Click({Return-DropDown});
$ret = $form.ShowDialog();

#################return values

return $textBox1.Text, $textBox2.Text, $textBox3.Text
}

$return= button “Enter Info” “First Name” “Last Name” “Email Address”
$return2 = ($return[0] + " " + $return[1])
$return3 = ($return[0] + "." + $return[1])
$return4 = $return[0] + "." + $return[1] + $return[2]


New-Mailbox -Alias $return3 -Name $return2 -FirstName $return[0] -LastName $return[1] -UserPrincipalName $return4  -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@ssw0rd' -AsPlainText -Force) -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true
Set-User -Identity $return3 -StreetAddress '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW' -City 'Washington' -StateOrProvince 'D.C.' -PostalCode '20500' -Phone '202-456-1111' -Fax '202-456-2461'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a little misleading but the error is saying that it does not know how to use the + operator with the `$return[0]` object. String and integers can work with the + operator for example.

You missed copying the entire error. Consider the following code. I will attempt to add a space to a folder name object incorrectly.

```
$folder = Get-Item "C:\temp"
$folder + " "

Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] doesn't contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:2 char:1
+ $folder + " "
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

`op_Addition` being the text that was truncated in your post.

**Your actual issue**

Even though you have a return statement a function will return **all** output back to the output stream. You need to pipe that extra output to null. Casting to `[void]` or piping to `Out-Null` are the two common approaches.

These lines are the actual issue

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
```

Need to pipe to null / void the output. (I see from an edit you already figured this out. )

```
[void]([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms"))
[void]([System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing"))
```

Comment: When i input it that way it brings up Cannot bind parameter 'Name' to the target. Exception setting "Name": "The length of the property is too long. The
maximum length is 64 and the length of the value provided is 169."
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [New-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailbox

Comment: @TylerS what does `$return2` 3,4 look like if you print them on the console?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5
0a3a
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5
0a3a
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5
0a3a0

Comment: @TylerS Yeah. I was wrong about your issue. Your function is returning more that you expected. You might have addressed it in your other answer. You need to to filter that output to null first.

Answer (score 0):

If I run this code it works fine. Does anyone have a way of inputting a dropdown box in the form ?

```
function button ($title,$mailbx, $WF, $TF) {

###################Load Assembly for creating form & button######

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)

#####Define the form size & placement

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 750;
$form.Height = 500;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;

##############Define text label1
$textLabel1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel1.Left = 25;
$textLabel1.Top = 15;

$textLabel1.Text = $mailbx;

##############Define text label2

$textLabel2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel2.Left = 25;
$textLabel2.Top = 50;

$textLabel2.Text = $WF;

##############Define text label3

$textLabel3 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel3.Left = 25;
$textLabel3.Top = 85;

$textLabel3.Text = $TF;

############Define text box1 for input
$textBox1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox1.Left = 150;
$textBox1.Top = 10;
$textBox1.width = 200;

############Define text box2 for input

$textBox2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox2.Left = 150;
$textBox2.Top = 50;
$textBox2.width = 200;

############Define text box3 for input

$textBox3 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox3.Left = 150;
$textBox3.Top = 90;
$textBox3.width = 200;

#############Define default values for the input boxes
$defaultValue = “”
$textBox1.Text = $defaultValue;
$textBox2.Text = $defaultValue;
$textBox3.Text = $defaultValue;

#############define OK button
$button = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$button.Left = 360;
$button.Top = 85;
$button.Width = 100;
$button.Text = “Ok”;

############# This is when you have to close the form after getting values
$eventHandler = [System.EventHandler]{
$textBox1.Text;
$textBox2.Text;
$textBox3.Text;
$form.Close();};

$button.Add_Click($eventHandler) ;

#############Add controls to all the above objects defined
$form.Controls.Add($button);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel1);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel2);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel3);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox2);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox3);
$ret = $form.ShowDialog();

#################return values

return $textBox1.Text, $textBox2.Text, $textBox3.Text
}

$return= button “Enter Info” “First Name” “Last Name” “Email Address”
$return2 = ($return[0] + " " + $return[1])
$return3 = ($return[0] + "." + $return[1])
$return4 = $return[0] + "." + $return[1] + $return[4]


New-Mailbox -Alias $return3 -Name $return2 -FirstName $return[0] -LastName $return[1] -UserPrincipalName $return4  -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@ssw0rd' -AsPlainText -Force) -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true
Set-User -Identity $return3 -StreetAddress '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW' -City 'Washington' -StateOrProvince 'D.C.' -PostalCode '20500' -Phone '202-456-1111' -Fax '202-456-2461'
```

Comment: Seems we both figured out your issue with this question. Since you are now having a different issue please consider making new question since this one has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error message but this was because of a mistake in the code:

```
$NUFirstname =  $mTextBox1
$NULastname  =  $mTextBox2
```

should be:

```
$NUFirstname =  $mTextBox1.text
$NULastname  =  $mTextBox2.text
```

Cheers,
Radegonda